# How can front- and backporch in TFT displays be inexact?

Tags: display, rgb, tft

Today I had the question as to why front- and backporches in TFT displays can vary. There is this image (from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnzhK5Vvvao) which shows the HSYNC, HBP, Active Width and HFP. This makes sense.

[image: Display timings from ST video]

Later in the video there are values listed in the datasheet which include a minimum, typical and maximum values for the front- and backporch. How can these timings vary since there seems to be no difference between the porches and the active area? In my understanding, this would make it impossible to deliver any product with a display at the correct location, since any fixed value could be incorrect and result in a shifted display.

This is obviously incorrect, but what am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not inexact. You can send any signal with exact timing parameters to the display, if the parameters are within the range of limits supported by the display.

It does not mean that each display has a random timing.

Only the active area is displayed.

The porches are required but they can have varying amounts of pixels or lines to be compatible with different horizontal and vertical timings your display controller sends to the display.

So the display just accepts any signal that has the parameters within the minimum and maximum range.

Comment: But how can the display determine what porch size is selected by the display controller? A single white pixel in the middle of the active area could be anywhere within the range of acceptable porch sizes...

Comment: The display controller sends what is active pixels with synchronizing signals. Depending on display it might be a single DE signal. Or separate H and V sync signals with the required timing.

Comment: Oh... You are right... After checking RGB interface timing diagrams it all makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> this would make it impossible to deliver any product with a display at the correct location, since any fixed value could be incorrect and result in a shifted display.

Think of the porches as WAIT times for the panel's display controller (inside the panel's circuitry). The controller IC (inside the panel) processes the data between SYNC pulses (some may require DE as well) *, and it just **ignores the porches as they don't carry any pixel data**.

Historically, the purpose of the porch timing might be different but I'll try to explain over a digital driving example:

When you send a HSYNC, the controller IC switches to next row for driving the panel (TFT LCD or whatever), zeroes the required internal counters, etc. So you should allow some time for the controller to prepare itself. This is where the horizontal back porch comes in. Then you send the active pixels which carry the actual data, and send another porch (horizontal front porch) as the controller IC knows how many horizontal pixels should (and have) come, all the latched data will be transferred to the respective line during that front porch delay. And the IC gets ready for another HSYNC if there's any lines remaining.

Display datasheets define horizontal and vertical "total" porches so it's up to designer how they will be divided (e.g. if the horizontal porch is given as 51 the designer can split this into 35 front and 16 back).

*: These are single pulses but the pulse widths are a few clock-pulse-long (horizontal or vertical clock).

Comment: Thanks for the additional context. I was speficially looking for the DE signal which solved my particular question. But I didn't yet know about the relation between the display and display IC.